# Setup for a wine bottle with multiple labels

Tags: modeling

I have modeled a wine bottle and created various wine label designs for a client. The labels were created in Illustrator and so I have PNGs. I want to present a render of the same bottle with each label the client. The labels are not simple rectangles.

Should I:

1. "model" each label and wrap it on the bottle, or
2. try to map each label image to a portion of the bottle's surface?

I've seen lots of tutorials showing option #2, but something is telling me that the glass of the bottle should be separate from the "paper" label.

Also, with #1, couldn't I use the same bottle blend file and use a different layer for the each label, then turn on a different layer for each new render?

Maybe there's an even better strategy?

thanks,

Comment: You can use the second way, *but* first model that paper label (by duplicating bottle surface and positioning it adjacent) and mapping image with label on that. Also it'll be a bit easier to map image then

Comment: Are the labels the same size? How many labels?

Comment: @Mr Zak Thanks, I did as you suggested in my first version. It worked, but I got some distortion at the edges of the label. I eventually went with the solution suggested by cegaton.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise There will be 3 versions to start and then revisions of the final label. Cegaton's solution worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an object that surrounds the bottle, but it's but that is just a bit bigger than the bottle (to avoid Z fighting errors). Unwrap it to get something like this:

[image]

Assign a texture using the alpha channel of the texture to control a transparent shader. A mapping node will also help you with the positioning of the label.

[image]

Now by changing the image on the Image texture node (and sometimes the scale and placement) you can preview your different labels.

[image]

A blend file to play:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was a great solution and having the screenshots was fantastic. I missed the blend file that you uploaded, but once I got it and loaded it up, I have some questions. My label art wrapped around the label mesh. I ended up getting rid ot the geometry in for the back side of the label mesh. How did you get yours to be confined to just the front? The scene setup was so different from anything I've seen presented before, but it created some very dramatic lighting. But that's what I'm trying to learn. Is there a site that specializes in lighting techniques?

Comment: Placement and size of the texture on the geometry is all done in the mapping node