# SVG file and Shrinkwrap modifier not working properly

Tags: modifiers, svg

I imported an SVG file into my project containing a bottle. The SVG file is supposed to be the label of the bottle and wrap around it however it seems to take on weird shapes when I apply the Shrinkwrap modifier or do it manually.
Previously I converted it to a mesh and combined all curves into one mesh.
[image]

Comment: I cannot tell from these images what is going wrong. You didn’t show more than one situation. What is the label supposed to look like? How does it start off (without the modifier)?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/using-svg-to-put-label-on-bottle https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40901/setup-for-a-wine-bottle-with-multiple-labels https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/what-is-the-right-way-to-apply-an-image-texture-over-a-glass-or-plastic-material